# Export NDB Datastore records to Cloud Storage CSV file

Tags: google-app-engine, csv, mapreduce, google-cloud-storage, app-engine-ndb

In my NDB Datastore I have more than 2 million records. I want to export these records grouped by `created_at` date into CSV files on Google Cloud Storage. I calculated that every file would then be about 1GB.

```
2014-03-18.csv, ~17000 records, ~1GB
2014-03-17.csv, ~17000 records, ~1GB
2014-03-18.csv, ~17000 records, ~1GB
...
```

My first approach (pseudo-code):

```
import cloudstorage as gcs
gcs_file = gcs.open(date + '.csv', 'w')
query = Item.query().filter(Item.created_at >= date).filter(Item.created_at < date+1day)
records = query.fetch_page(50, cursor)
for record in records:
   gcs_file.write(record)
```

But this (obviously?) leads into memory issues:

```
Error: Exceeded soft private memory limit with 622.16 MB after servicing 2 requests total
```

---

Should I use a MapReduce Pipeline instead or is there any way to make approach 1 work? If using MapReduce: Could I filter for `created_at` without iterating over all records in NDB?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124398/in-google-app-engine-how-to-i-reduce-memory-consumption-as-i-write-a-file-out-t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out. Since all data is in NDB datastore I wasn't really able to test everything locally, so I found `logging.info("Memory Usage: %s", runtime.memory_usage().current())` extremely helpful. (Import with `from google.appengine.api import runtime`).

**The problem is the "In-Context Cache":** query results are written back to the in-context cache. [More information.](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/cache)
See an [example to disable the In-Context Cache](https://gist.github.com/mattes/9646173#file-gae_csv-py-L17) for an Entity Kind.

My calculation was slightly wrong though. A generated CVS file is about 300 MB big. It is generated/ saved to Google Cloud Storage within 5 minutes.

[image: Memory consumption without gc.collect()]

Peak memory consumption was about 480MB.

In comparison, with an added `gc.collect()` in the `while True:` loop ([link](https://gist.github.com/mattes/9646173/6a1f7bd9321967bb4929dc7d4e60f2fe6d97a5d9#file-gae_csv-py-L28)) as suggested by @brian in the comment above, the memory consumption peak was about 260MB. But it took quite long, about 20 minutes.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Considering the number of records, it seems obvious indeed that you get a memory error. 
The garbage collector is called by default when the request ends, which explains why the memory used is increasing like this.

In this kind of situation what I usually do is calling the garbage collector manually with `gc.collect()` after each page is fetched.

It would look something like this:

```
import cloudstorage as gcs
import gc

cursor = None
more = True
gcs_file = gcs.open(date + '.csv', 'w')
query = Item.query().filter(Item.created_at >= date).filter(Item.created_at < date+1day)

while more:
  records, cursor, more = query.fetch_page(50, cursor)
  gc.collect()
  for record in records:
    gcs_file.write(record)

gcs_file.close()
```

It has been working for me in many cases.

Comment: good idea. it is giving me the same error though, unfortunately. Not sure how the ` gcs_file.write(record)` works, yet. If this functions buffers everything first, then this would be a problem.

Comment: Shouldn't `gc.collect()` go inside the loop?

Comment: He says this is pseudo-code so I guess there's another loop around. He writes records 50 per 50, so to me there's no need to put the gc.collect() inside the for loop. the gcs_file.write method should write in chunks into cloud storage. @mattes can you show the actual code you're using, just to be sure ?

Comment: added `gc.collect()` after line 26 (https://gist.github.com/mattes/9646173#file-gae_csv-py-L26).

Comment: It looks fine to me. Do you get the memory error during the first iteration ?

Comment: One iteration works. (Here is how I verified it: https://gist.github.com/mattes/9646173/6a1f7bd9321967bb4929dc7d4e60f2fe6d97a5d9#file-gae_csv-py-L40)

Comment: i manually quit the `while True:` after 10 and 50 loops. 10 iterations work, 50 will fail. all with `pages_query.fetch_page(50, ...`

Answer (score 0):

The in context cache might be part of your issue, but fetch_page in general is a leaky method.  If you're doing repeated queries, wrap your work in @ndb.toplevel so queues are cleared in between queries and garbage collection can be more effective.