# Export Data From Cloud Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine

Many years ago I wrote an app on Google App Engine. I saved over 100,000 entries.
Here's the code I used to store it in the blob. Now I want to export all the data. Ideally, I would have prefered to download all these entries as a csv but there is no option on the backend. How can I easily download all the data I have saved over the years?

```
import webapp2

from google.appengine.ext import ndb


class Database(ndb.Model):
    """Models an individual user entry with email, app, and date."""
    email = ndb.StringProperty()
    app = ndb.StringProperty()
    platform = ndb.StringProperty()
    date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

class add(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def post(self):
      e = self.request.get("email")
      a = self.request.get("app")
      p = self.request.get("platform")

      b = e+', '+a+', '+p

      u = Database()

      u.email = e
      u.app = a
      u.platform = p

      u.put()
```

Is there a way to get all of my data? I cannot output all the data on a webpage. It crashes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export data from Google App Engine to csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33360370/export-data-from-google-app-engine-to-csv)

Comment: Also interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22511152/export-ndb-datastore-records-to-cloud-storage-csv-file

Comment: Thanks Dan, the first link did the trick!